# Single word for 'increasingly convinced'

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that represents a 'growing conviction' or 'increasingly convinced'?

For example:

> Montag's growing conviction of the importance of books is evident by the end of the first section.

or

> Montag becomes increasingly convinced of the importance of books by the end of the first section.

Answer (score 1):

Montag's **certainty** of the importance of books is evident by the end of the first section.

**certainty**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/certainty)

> 1. The fact, quality, or state of being certain, especially: a. Inevitability: the certainty of death. b. The quality of being
>      established as true: the certainty that the earth orbits the sun. c.
>      Confidence; assurance: his certainty that things would get better.

Answer (score 1):

persuade
[per-sweyd]
verb (used with object), per·suad·ed, per·suad·ing.

2. to induce to believe by appealing to reason or understanding; convince:

[Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/persuade)

“Montag is persuaded about the importance of books by the end of the first section.”

Answer (score 0):

You can use "acceptance" or a synonym of it.

> **acceptance**:
>
> 3. Agreement with or belief in an idea or explanation.
>      [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/acceptance)

So from your sentences:

> Montag's *acceptance* of the importance of books is evident by the end of the first section

Answer (score 0):

'Burgeoning' is a good word for what you are trying to convey. However, you would still need 'conviction': 'burgeoning conviction'. 'Burgeoning' means something budding - beginning to grow. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/burgeon